# Issue in .net remoting on a PC with multiple NIC cards

Tags: .net, remoting

We are hosting a component in .net remoting ,on a PC(Server PC) which has multiple NIC's. I have another PC (Client PC) connected privately to this PC thru one of the NIC. When trying to access the component hosted in server PC,I am getting the below error.
**A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network:*IPAddress of another NIC*: Port number**

I have also tried binding the IP address to the server component's remoting channel(remoting configuration below).

```
 <system.runtime.remoting>
        <application>
          <channels>
            <channel ref="tcp" name="SERVER_CHANNEL" priority="40" port="0" machineName="IL-TRACK" bindTo="10.10.10.4">
              <serverProviders>
                <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full" />
              </serverProviders>
              <clientProviders>
                <provider type="Utilities.SinkProvider, Infrastructure.Utilis" />
                <formatter ref="binary" />
              </clientProviders>
            </channel>
          </channels>
        </application>
        <customErrors mode="off" />
      </system.runtime.remoting>
```

What am I missing here?

**NOTE:** I have turned off firewall in both server and client PC's.
When I restart the server PC ,it works fine for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,We found the problem.The problem was there were multiple remoting channels in the Appdomain and eveything had same priorities,so my application was using the wrong channel all the time and this channel did not have any specific binding to it.

I increased the priority for the channel which it is supposed to use,then everything started working